# Insert a row above, every time the value of a cell in a column differs from the one above

Tags: excel, vba

I am using a datasheet wherein the value of my cell differs after a couple rows (variable).

Every time the value of the cell differs, as we keep moving down, I want to add a row above that cell.

I tried nested for loops because the first loop will be used to carry out the second loop 61 times (the number of times cell changes occur):

```
Sub jcapp()
  Dim i As Integer
  Dim j As Integer
  Static k As Integer
  Dim l As Integer
  With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    k = 3
    For l = 1 To 61
      For i = k + 1 To 175    
        j = k
        If .Cells(i, 2).Value <> .Cells(i - 1, 2).Value And Not 
        IsEmpty(.Cells(i, 2).Value) Then
          k = i
          Rows(.Cells(i + 1, 1).Row).Insert shift:=xlDown
        End If
        Exit For
      Next i
    Next l
  End With
End Sub
```

I expect the addition of rows at 9th row, 20th row, etc. whenever the cell value changes. Nothing is happening. There is no result.

Comment: You'll have to use a `worksheet_change` event: https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/events.html#worksheet-change-event

Comment: Could not understand the problem clearly. However You are using two nested for loop both with same variable i. other issues are  j is not used, k is being assigned with .i and above all `Exit For` is being used outside If branch leading to exit the inside loop on 1st iteration. `Exit For` generally used if some condition satisfied and no further looping is necessary. May try to describe what you want to achieve or add the post with images of the initial and result data.

Comment: Why the left-justified code? Logical indentation of loops, etc. makes code more readable, both for others and even for yourself (and thus helps in debugging).

Answer (score 0):

Inserting (or deleting) throws the index off.

Instead of trying to keep track of the number of rows a standard method is to loop in reverse.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub jcapp()

    Dim i As Long

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

        For i = 61 To 2 Step -1

            If .Cells(i, 2).Value <> .Cells(i - 1, 2).Value Then
                Debug.Print i
                .Rows(.Cells(i, 1).Row).Insert shift:=xlDown
            End If

        Next i

    End With

End Sub
```